# Looking for dataset of the coordinates of the UK NUTS Levels

Tags: geospatial, uk

I cannot find the coordinates of the UK NUTS levels. There are resources which tell what the name and the code of NUTS regions are. But they do not provide what are their coordinates! I need a dataset which should include the NUTS name and the lat/long that surround the area.
Data can be in any standard formats, e.g. CSV or Geojson.

Comment: If this is open data it may be worth asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the NUTS regions in various formats from [EUROStat](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts) or they provide [a REST API](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/distribution/v2/nuts/).

Comment: Thanks for the edit and your reply. But it seems this is a dataset for Euro, is there a similar one for the UK only? Many thanks

Comment: No, EUROStat now provide a EU27 without the UK though! You can easily select just the UK in QGis or any other GIS editor. I didn't explore the API so maybe there